# Problem using hibernate with Netbeans

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I using hibernate with netbeans. It's my first time. I'm following this tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#01

All is well, except when I come to the part "Creating the Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs
". The problem is no classes are being generated. My hibernate.reveng.xml also seems to be short since it contains only this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="sakila"/>
  <table-filter match-name="category"/>
  <table-filter match-name="film_category"/>
  <table-filter match-name="actor"/>
  <table-filter match-name="film_actor"/>
  <table-filter match-name="film"/>
  <table-filter match-name="language"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Any ideas please? 
10x a lot! 
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 1):

Please check your "hibernate.cfg.xml". I think the problem should be that it contains an entry

org.hibernate.hql.classic.**ClassicQueryTransactionFactory**

See the content I have highlighted. It should be

org.hibernate.hql.classic.**ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory**

It worked for me.

Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Hibernate is case sensitive, but Netbeans, when you use the "Hibernate configuration wizard", and the "Hibernate Reverse Engeenering" creates de files with the database name in lowcase.
The exact name of the Database is "sakila"? Or it's possible it that would be named "Sakila" or similar?
If you change both files (xxxxxxx.cfg.xml and xxxxxxx.reveng.xml) I think it will work fine.

Regards